# Compute car payment amount not calculating properly

Tags: c++

I am creating a small program for a homework assignment. The program runs correctly except the calculation is not correct.

The formula I am using to calculate the payment amount is:

Payment = (intRate * (1+intRate)^N / ((1+intRate)^N-1)) * L

Where "N" is the number of payments and "L" is the principal. The code I wrote to do this is:

```
monthlyPayment = (intRate * pow ((1 + intRate), numberPayments) / (intRate * pow ((1 +     intRate), numberPayments)-1))*principal;
```

The complete code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double principal, intRate, paybackAmount, interestPaid,  monthlyPayment;
    int numberPayments;

    // Change the panel color.
    system ("color F0");

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "This application will calculate your loan amounts." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the data below." << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Loan Amount: ";
    cin >> principal;
    cout << "Monthly Interest Rate: ";
    cin >> intRate;
    cout << "Number of Payments: ";
    cin >> numberPayments;


    cout << "\n\n\n";

    monthlyPayment = (intRate * pow ((1 + intRate), numberPayments) / (intRate *     pow ((1 + intRate), numberPayments)-1))*principal;
    paybackAmount = monthlyPayment * numberPayments;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint << left << setw(24) << "Loan     Amount:" << "$" << setw(11) << right << principal << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << showpoint<< left << setw(24) << "Monthly     Interest Rate:" << setw(11) << right << intRate << "%" << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(0) << left << setw(24) << "Number of Payments:"     << setw(12) << right << numberPayments << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint<< left << setw(24) << "Monthly     Payment:" << "$" << setw(11) << right << monthlyPayment << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint<< left << setw(24) << "Amount     Paid Back:" << "$" << setw(11) << right << paybackAmount << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint<< left << setw(24) << "Interest     Paid:" << "$" << right << setw(11) << paybackAmount - principal << "\n\n" << endl;


    system("pause");
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, but break that habit of `using namespace std;`. Refer to `cout` as `std::cout`. Using qualified names will save you a great deal of pain in the future.

Comment: @PeteBecker Possibly every (small) C++ program that uses `std` I've ever written contains `using namespace std;`. It may not be a very good practice (and downright irresponsible for large projects), but it sure does make code prettier.

Comment: @Dukeling - beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Our instructor requires the use of "using namespace std;"

Answer (score 1):

You're multiplying both the numerator and denominator by `intRate`, when you should only be multiplying the numerator, according to the your equation.

You're also subtracting 1 from the result of the second `pow` rather than from `numberPayments`.

```
(intRate * pow ((1 + intRate), numberPayments)-1)
//  ^ Why is this here?            Wrong place ^
```

What you actually want is:

```
monthlyPayment = (intRate * pow(1+intRate, numberPayments) /
                            pow(1+intRate, numberPayments-1)) * principal;
```

Comment: That was a boneheaded mistake. Thanks. However, the calculation is still wrong? I get...                                                   


Loan Amount:            $   10000.00
Monthly Interest Rate:          1.0%
Number of Payments:               36
Monthly Payment:        $   10000.00
Amount Paid Back:       $  360000.00
Interest Paid:          $  350000.00

Comment: @Loki Astari - Guys thanks for the help! I made the change but still come up with the wrong math. Now I get....                              Loan Amount:            $   10000.00
Monthly Interest Rate:          1.0%
Number of Payments:               36
Monthly Payment:        $   20000.00
Amount Paid Back:       $  720000.00
Interest Paid:          $  710000.00

Comment: @KevinSchultz Try entering it all without unit signs (`$` and `%`) and give the interest rate as `0.01`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have extra intRate

```
  `(intRate * pow ((1 +     intRate), numberPayments)-1))*principal;`
   ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an extra argument has been slipped in:

```
((1+intRate)^N-1)) * L => (intRate * pow ((1 + intRate), numberPayments)-1))*principal
//                         ^^^^^^^^^  Look Odd.
```

Additionally:

```
(1+intRate)^N-1
```

You represent this as:

```
pow ((1 + intRate), numberPayments)-1
```

I would have done that differently as:

```
pow ((1 + intRate), (numberPayments-1))
```